# Javascript loop through Json

Tags: javascript, json

Trying to figure out how to loop through `users` in the following Json response:

```
{ "id": 23, "users": { "26": "user 333", "27": "user 222" } }
```

A normal for-loop is not working, i.e `for(i = 0; i <object.users.length; i++)`. So I started thinking maybe it's not a normal array because there are no `[]` brackets. But even the simplest operation fails: `alert(object.users[0])`.

I need help figuring out how I can loop through each user and get both key and value (`key:value`).

Comment: `users` is not an array. It's an object

Comment: Use a for in loop.

Comment: `for (var userId in object.users) { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var json = { "id": 23, "users": { "26": "user 333", "27": "user 222" } } ;
for(var ob in json['users']){
 console.log(ob,json['users'][ob]);
}
```

Use [for- in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to loop through objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (a loop on the keys of your sub-object):

```
for(var u in object.users){
    var user = object.users[u];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
for(var u in object.users){
    var user = object.users[u];
}
```

Comment: please elaborate on this solution, and/or include references

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```js
var obj = { "id": 23, "users": { "26": "user 333", "27": "user 222" } };
for(var i in obj.users)
 console.log(i+': '+obj.users[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help

```
 var response = { "id": 23, "users": { "26": "user 333", "27": "user 222" }};

              var usersVar = response.users;
                 for(var key in usersVar){
                   console.log(usersVar[key]);
                 }
```